# Why is the pandas merge between these two dataframes looking like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df_day` down below as you can see

```
            Day
2022-05-02  2
2022-05-03  3
2022-05-04  4
2022-05-05  5
2022-05-06  6
2022-05-07  7
2022-05-08  8
2022-05-09  9
2022-05-10  10
2022-05-11  11
2022-05-12  12
2022-05-13  13
2022-05-14  14
2022-05-15  15
2022-05-16  16
2022-05-17  17
2022-05-18  18
2022-05-19  19
2022-05-20  20
2022-05-21  21
2022-05-22  22
2022-05-23  23
2022-05-24  24
2022-05-25  25
2022-05-26  26
2022-05-27  27
2022-05-28  28
2022-05-29  29
2022-05-30  30
2022-05-31  31
2022-06-01  1
2022-06-02  2
2022-06-03  3
2022-06-04  4
```

and a dataframe `df_count` down below as you can also see

```
    Weekday Day Count
0   Mon     2   44
1   Tue     3   44
2   Wed     4   32
3   Thu     5   26
4   Fri     6   39
5   Sat     7   39
0   Mon     9   37
1   Tue    10   30
2   Wed    11   33
3   Thu    12   41
4   Fri    13   36
5   Sat    14   38
0   Mon    16   32
1   Tue    17   35
2   Wed    18   35
3   Thu    19   31
4   Fri    20   44
5   Sat    21   31
0   Mon    23   57
1   Tue    24   32
2   Wed    25   34
3   Thu    26   42
4   Fri    27   42
5   Sat    28   29
0   Mon    30   33
1   Tue    31   33
2   Wed    1    33
3   Thu    2    33
4   Fri    3    33
5   Sat    4    33
```

and when I try to merge them using `df_merged = pd.merge(df_day, df_count, 'outer')`

I get this resultant dataframe which isn't supposed to look like this to be honest

```
    Day Weekday Count
0   2   Mon     44.0
1   2   Thu     33.0
2   2   Mon     44.0
3   2   Thu     33.0
4   3   Tue     44.0
5   3   Fri     33.0
6   3   Tue     44.0
7   3   Fri     33.0
8   4   Wed     32.0
9   4   Sat     33.0
10  4   Wed     32.0
11  4   Sat     33.0
12  5   Thu     26.0
13  6   Fri     39.0
14  7   Sat     39.0
15  8   NaN     NaN
16  9   Mon     37.0
17  10  Tue     30.0
18  11  Wed     33.0
19  12  Thu     41.0
20  13  Fri     36.0
21  14  Sat     38.0
22  15  NaN     NaN
23  16  Mon     32.0
24  17  Tue     35.0
25  18  Wed     35.0
26  19  Thu     31.0
27  20  Fri     44.0
28  21  Sat     31.0
29  22  NaN     NaN
30  23  Mon     57.0
31  24  Tue     32.0
32  25  Wed     34.0
33  26  Thu     42.0
34  27  Fri     42.0
35  28  Sat     29.0
36  29  NaN     NaN
37  30  Mon     33.0
38  31  Tue     33.0
39  1   Wed     33.0
```

What is going on with the top portion of this dataframe `df_merged` ?

```
0   2   Mon     44.0
1   2   Thu     33.0
2   2   Mon     44.0
3   2   Thu     33.0
4   3   Tue     44.0
5   3   Fri     33.0
6   3   Tue     44.0
7   3   Fri     33.0
8   4   Wed     32.0
9   4   Sat     33.0
10  4   Wed     32.0
11  4   Sat     33.0
```

[Day] should 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. Weekday should be Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri. etc.

If I do `df_merged = pd.merge(df_day, df_count, left_on='Day', right_on='Day', how='right')`

Then it almost looks accurate, but still not quite:

```
    Day Weekday Count
0   2   Mon     44
1   2   Mon     44
2   3   Tue     44
3   3   Tue     44
4   4   Wed     32
5   4   Wed     32
6   5   Thu     26
7   6   Fri     39
8   7   Sat     39
9   9   Mon     37
10  10  Tue     30
11  11  Wed     33
12  12  Thu     41
13  13  Fri     36
14  14  Sat     38...etc.
```

Comment: You merge on the common columns, here only "Day", as you have multiple days 2/3/4 you get all combinations in the merge, irrespective of the date or weekday.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. In my previous trial runs it was working because I was using 4 weeks for my data, and the days in the week never overlapped. If its 5 weeks, its going to overlap, causing the issue. Now the question is how to resolve it...

Comment: If you have more than one month, you can't unfortunately. There is no way to unambiguously map a full date with just the dow and day. If I tell you Sat 5, what is the date? In 2022 this could be 2022-02-05 or 2022-03-05 or 2022-11-05...

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the type of merge and columns to join:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_day, df_count, left_on = 'Day', right_on = 'Day', how = 'left')
```

Let us know if this code helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately no that did not help.